# How to use Github actions to run jest unit tests

Tags: reactjs, github, yaml, github-actions, mern

I keep getting the following error when I proceed to run a workflow:

```
Run npm test
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/armoire/armoire/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/armoire/armoire/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-11-12T17_08_44_277Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

The yaml workflow being:

```
name: frontendTesting
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing her frontend
on: [push]
jobs:
  check-bats-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm install -g bats
      - run: bats -v
  run-unit-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: cd frontend
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test
```

I think the error is because I do not have a package.json where .github/workflows is. I have two folders : frontend and backend. Their respective package.json files are in those folders.
How can I fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The fix was fairly simple, you just have to redirect to where the package.json is using "working-directory" - for example:

```
name: frontendTesting
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing her frontend
on: [push]
jobs:
  run-defined-frontend-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run test
```